# How to convert excel files with multiple sheets to 1 csv file?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

> > You seem to have misinterpreted my message. I can split the sheet into many csv files. What I want is to have it all in one file in dataframe format. The current issue is that when I load the converted csv file, it does not match the appearance of the excel. Some columns are missing or misaligned. I was unable to access it via dataframe since everything is mismatched.

I downloaded the Eurostat data in Excel format. I'd like to convert to csv so that I can work with the data frame more easily. Unfortunately, when I accessed the data frame after converting it, it displayed NANs. The excel file has multiple sheets (over 30). How can I work with this file type? How do I proceed with converting it? I have 10 excel files, each with 30 sheets. I'd like to archive it all in one file. Do you have any suggestions?
Here is the original file look like.

[excel file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0ZrT.png)

After concatenate into the dataframes in one csv file

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YdxO.png)

```
folder_path = 'file'
dfs = []

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'): 
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        
        try:
            df = pd.read_excel(file_path)  # Modify parameters if needed
            dfs.append(df)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading file '{filename}': {str(e)}")


combined_df = pd.concat(dfs)

combined_df.to_csv('combined_data.csv', index=False)
```

I expect that the data frame will display a list of countries, durations, and product names.

Comment: Are you trying to convert each excel file into 30 csv files ?

Comment: @HimanshuPanwar No, it should have only 1 csv file containing 30 sheets of excel.

Comment: CSV does not support multiple sheets/tabs. You can create separate csv files for each sheet.

Comment: @HimanshuPanwar I understand that. I can do separate csv files. The problem is it does not represent the same in excel. That's where I lost.

Comment: Is your problem that any conversion to CSV is misaligned with `NaN`s, even with one file per sheet, in addition to the problem that you don't know how to create one file from 30 sheets?

Comment: @Vercingatorix yes, even only one file per sheet. With several sheets in one files causes more problem. I guess I need something that make to stay in place before converting. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You have the option of downloading the Eurostat data in tab-separated value format (TSV). This is essentially the same as CSV, just a different delimiter. There is also "SDMX-CSV", which looks like a form of CSV. Does this resolve your problem? If not, how do you want to organize the sheets since each one represents different concepts (import, export, total, extra, intra, etc.)?

Comment: @Vercingatorix actually, I solved a problem by exporting the file in tsv from Eurostat. I tried to do it with Excel. It's so hectic. Thank you very much. 

Comment: Yes, it is complicated. I was working on an answer for you but I'm glad the TSV file serves your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure you are going down the right path [as you ended up realizing], and here are [for posterity] the reasons.

The problems with the `NaN`s you are experiencing is because you are attempting to read a complex spreadsheet, which contains a lot of non-numerical data and headers and other overhead, using a tool that is intended for simple matrixes of numbers. Put another way, a dataframe is intended, as far as I can tell, to hold the core of your data (rows 10-40 of `Sheet 1` through `Sheet 12` or whatever is in your example, with possibly a variable number of columns), but you are attempting to read in the whole spreadsheet.

There are ways to work around some of this; for example, you can use the `header` parameter of `read_excel` to identify the column header, or in your case, column headers. (You may have to use `MultiIndex` for this.) In your case, the header is in rows 10, 11, and 12. You can can use `skiprows` to skip over the first nine rows, which `pandas` doesn't really understand how to parse. (But these rows do contain important data I think you need, viz. `PARTNER`, `PRODUCT`, `FLOW`, etc.; this is part of why I think you may be going down a rabbit hole.) `usecols`, `skipfooter`, and `nrows` can be used to further trim the data to just the numbers and their labels.

But, unfortunately, while this gets you data that contains minimal or no `NaN` values, the next question is, how are you going to organize it into your CSV file? You can't just append it, because, like I said, each sheet constitutes different data (`Sheet 1` contains `Extra-EU27` `IMPORT` data; `Sheet 2` contains `Extra-EU27` `EXPORT` data; `Sheet 3` contains `Extra-EU27` `TOTAL` data; and so forth), and that data must be identified in the CSV file, and it might be difficult to identify this data. (You'd have to either rely on this information being in cells C5 and C6 and find a way to read these cells in `pandas`, or some other tool, or you'd have to actually parse the spreadsheet.)

You have the option of downloading the Eurostat data in tab-separated value format (TSV). This is essentially the same as CSV, just a different delimiter. There is also "SDMX-CSV", which looks like a form of CSV. [This ended up how you solved the problem.]

Comment: Now everything is all good with tsv file. Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

f you want to get all of the sheets, you can pass sheet_name=None to the read_excel() call. This will then return a dictionary containing each sheet name as a key, with the value being the dataframe. With this you can iterate over each and create separate CSV files.

The following example uses a base filename with the sheetname appended, e.g. output_sheet1.csv output_sheet2.csv:

```py
import pandas as pd

for sheet_name, df in pd.read_excel(r"input.xlsx", index_col=0, sheet_name=None).items():
    df.to_csv(f'output_{sheet_name}.csv', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can load the excel file using `pandas.ExcelFile` and get the sheet names using `sheet_names` attribute. Then loop over individual sheet_names and open the excel for that sheet.

Updated your code as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

folder_path = 'file'
dfs = []

for filename in os.listdir(folder_path):
    if filename.endswith('.xlsx'): 
        file_path = os.path.join(folder_path, filename)
        
        try:
            df = pd.ExcelFile(file_path)  # Modify parameters if needed
            dfs = [pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name) for sheet_name in df.sheet_names]
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Error reading file '{filename}': {str(e)}")

combined_df = pd.concat(dfs)

combined_df.to_csv('combined_data.csv', index=False)
```